# The middle point for KL divergence

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

Suppose I have two discrete $n$-dimensional distributions $P$ and $Q$.
Is there a *closed* formula for a distribution $X$ that has equal distance from $P$ and $Q$. Namely, $X$ is a distribution that satisfies
$$D_{KL}(P\|X) = D_{KL}(Q\|X)$$

Comment: First of all, I assume that you mean that $P$ and $Q$ have identical support. Even then, are you sure that such a distribution $X$ is unique?

Comment: P and Q are defined on the same set of variables, x_1,...,x_n. Even if X is not unique, give a closed form of one such solution. I think that X is unique as it is the min of f(X)=(DKL(P‖X)-DKL(Q‖X))^2, and this function has a unique min, no?

Comment: I don't think so. Let $P=(p_0,p_1, p_2, p_3)$ and $Q=(q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)$ with $p_2=p_3$ and $q_2=q_3$. You may choose an $X=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $D(P\Vert X)=D(Q\Vert X)$, but then $X=(x_0,x_1,x_3,x_2)$ also satisfies this equation.

Comment: OK. I don't really care about uniqueness. You may assume that P and Q are different entry-wise. I just need a closed form.

Comment: Or even assume that all the entries in P and Q are different (i.e. no number occurs twice).